# Store NGRX : can't get value from store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am currently doing a basic NGRX store.

I want a value in my Store (value called `chipSelected: string`), display that value in `AA.component.ts` and change it in `BB.component.ts` (through a button).

So I want my value displayed in AA.Component.ts initialized with my state initialState, and when I change it in BB.component.ts (through a button), my display var should be changed to.

This is currently what I have :

**AA.component.ts**

```
 chipSelected$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(
    public emailService: EmailService,
    private store: Store<EmailState>
  ) {
    this.chipSelected$ = this.store.select('chipSelected').pipe(
      map((chipSelected: string) => {
        return chipSelected;
      })
    );
  }
```

**AA.component.html**

{{chipSelected$ | async}}

**BB.component.ts**

```
constructor(private store: Store<EmailState>) {}
  //Triggered when button clicked
  setChip(): void {
    console.log("button clicked!")
    this.store.dispatch(changeChip({ chipSelected: 'newValue' }));
  }
```

**email.state.ts**

```
export const initialEmailState: EmailState = {
  chipSelected: 'oldValue',
};

export interface EmailState {
  chipSelected: 'oldValue' | 'newValue';
}
```

**email.actions.ts**

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';

export const changeChip = createAction(
  '[Email component] change chip selection',
  props<{ chipSelected: string }>()
);
```

**email.reducer.ts**

```
import { Action, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as EmailAction from './email.actions';
import { EmailState, initialEmailState } from './email.state';

const changeChipReducer = (
  state: EmailState,
  action: ReturnType<typeof EmailAction.changeChip>
): EmailState => ({
  ...state,
  chipSelected: action.chipSelected,
});

export const emailReducer = createReducer(
  initialEmailState,
  on(EmailAction.changeChip, changeChipReducer)
);
```

In app.module.ts (in which I import my EmailModule)
`StoreModule.forRoot({ root: emailReducer })`,

In my console, I have "Button clicked" printed.
But on my view, I have not "oldValue" where I display my Observable, nor "newValue" when I click on the button. I have nothing displayed :'(

I don't see the action pass in my Redux Devtools, so I don't think it passed...

Like if my store and my component are not well declared... ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall, your code posted looks fine, the only thing missing is a proper `selector`. You have `this.store.select('chipSelected')` but, where is `chipSelected` declared/defined?, it should be in the `Email` selectors:

```js
// somewhere in the store
export interface AppState {
  email: EmailState;
}

// email.selectors.ts
export const selectEmail = (state: AppState) => state.email;
export const selectChip = createSelector(selectEmail, (email) => email.chipSelected);
```

Then, in your component:

```js
import * as EmailSelectors from 'myfolder/store/email/selectors/email.selectors';

ngOnInit(): void {
  // don't need to pipe it, the selector already returns what you need
  // notice I didn't write manually "selectChip"
  this.chipSelected$ = this.store.select(EmailSelectors.selectChip);
}
```

For more information about `selectors`, I recommend reading the [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

I added :

// app.component.ts
export interface AppState {
  email: EmailState;
}

// email.selectors.ts
export const selectEmail = (state: AppState) => state.email;

export const selectChip = createSelector(
  selectEmail,
  (emailState: EmailState) => emailState.chipSelected
);

And in my component : 
Added this in constructor : 
private store: Store<AppState>

And : chipSelected$ = this.store.select(EmailSelectors.selectChip);

But still nothing in my component... Other ideas please ? Maybe something I missed ?